# Labeling distinct objects produced by Show[RegionPlot3D's]

Tags: graphics3d, labeling

I have these commands

```
j0=Q1>0&&Q2>0&&Q3>0&&Q1+3 Q2+2 Q3<1;j1=j0&&Q1^2+3 Q2 Q1+(3 Q2+Q3)^2<3 Q2+2 Q1 Q3;Choi=2 Q3+1<2 Q1+3 Q2;MUB=Q1>3 Q2+4 Q3;Show[RegionPlot3D[j1,{Q1,0,1/2},{Q2,0,1/3},{Q3,0,1/4},AxesLabel->{"Subscript[Q, 1]","Subscript[Q, 2]","Subscript[Q, 3]"}],RegionPlot3D[j0&&MUB,{Q1,0,1/2},{Q2,0,1/3},{Q3,0,1/4},AxesLabel->{"Subscript[Q, 1]","Subscript[Q, 2]","Subscript[Q, 3]"}],RegionPlot3D[j0&&Choi,{Q1,0,1/2},{Q2,0,1/3},{Q3,0,1/4},AxesLabel->{"Subscript[Q, 1]","Subscript[Q, 2]","Subscript[Q, 3]"}],RegionPlot3D[j1&&MUB,{Q1,0,1/2},{Q2,0,1/3},{Q3,0,1/4},AxesLabel->{"Subscript[Q, 1]","Subscript[Q, 2]","Subscript[Q, 3]"}]]
```

which produces a three-dimensional plot

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/34c06e57-f136-424f-852a-6c8ad5928b08

I want to label the first (largest) object produced "PPT", the second object, "MUB", and the third object, "Choi". How might I proceed to do so?

Also, I'd appreciate any general recommendations on enhancement/presentation of the plot (coloring,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plots = RegionPlot3D[#, {Q1, 0, 1/2}, {Q2, 0, 1/3}, {Q3, 0, 1/4}] & /@ 
  {j1, j0 && MUB, j0 && Choi};

coords = Cases[#, GraphicsComplex[x_,__] :> Median/@Transpose[x], All][[1]]& /@ plots;
labels = {"PPT", "MUB", "CHOI"};
texts3d = Graphics3D[MapThread[Text, {labels, coords}], Axes -> True];

Show[plots, texts3d, AxesLabel -> (Subscript[Q, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3})]
```

[image]

Comment: Good, and thanks, but I don't perceive the "MUB" label.

Comment: @Paul, changed the text coordinates for better placement of labels.

Comment: Good. I'll give a check to the answer. Any point/value in the use of different colors,...? (I'm not very knowledgeable in the graphics options,...) Could the labels be made to stand out more prominently? Just wondering about these things--thanks very much in any case.

Comment: @Paul, you can use something like  `texts3d = Graphics3D[MapThread[Text[Style[#, Red, Bold, FontSize -> 16], #2]&, {labels, coords}], Axes -> True]` to make the labels stand out.

Comment: Wow, they really stand out with that last suggestion!